# Only one NGINX Server Context works at a time for NGINX sites-enabled

Tags: nginx, docker, reverse-proxy

I have the following structure I am working with for NGINX

```
/etc/nginx
   - nginx.conf
   - conf.d
     - a.conf-disabled (I appended 'disabled' so it wont be used)
     - b.conf-disabled (I appended 'disabled' so it wont be used)
   - sites-available
     - a
     - b
   - sites-enabled
     - a (sym link to sites-available/a)
     - b (sym link to sites-available/b)
```

The `nginx.conf` file looks like the following:

```
worker_processes  4;
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

The `a` file in `sites-available` looks like the following:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name a;
    location /a/ {
            proxy_pass http://172.17.0.20:5678/;
    }
}
```

and the `b` file in `sites-available` looks like the following:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name b;
    location /b/ {
            proxy_pass http://172.17.0.20:5678/;
    }
 }
```

I am aware these pointing at the same address, I am just using it because I want to be able to test `/a` and `/b` separately.

The problem I am having is that only `/a` will work and `/b` fails. If I remove `a`, then `/b` works fine.

For example:

```
curl -X GET http://container-ip/a/ -> WORKS FINE
curl -X GET http://container-ip/b/ -> DOESN'T WORK
```

I ran logs and its not complaining about anything, but does fail with this when I try to hit `/b`.

```
2015/07/13 04:51:59 [error] 235#235: *58 "/etc/nginx/html/b/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: 10.0.2.2, server: , request: "GET /b/ HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8181"
```

Comment: why you bind with `server_name` but `curl` with container ip?

Comment: @Freeznet partially because I dont know what I am doing, and partially because it was just one of the hundred random things I tried :)

Comment: @Freeznet I am going to try to create another post that focuses more on what I need to accomplish and will link to it.

Comment: @Freeznet I have created another post that hopefully details the problem in more depth. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31386354/how-do-i-setup-nginx-configuration-to-reverse-proxy-to-multiple-containers-using