# How do I setup NGINX configuration to reverse proxy to multiple containers using different proxies and site files

Tags: nginx, proxy, docker, reverse-proxy

I am working on setting up our development environment using `Vagrant`, `Docker` and `NGINX` (among other tools).

We have a common microservice architecture and we are using a container per microservice.

As a proof of concept, I am using two test microservices to try to work out the development environment, `a` and `b`.

We are running three containers (`nginx,a,b`) for the purpose of my proof of concept.

Using reverse proxies in NGINX, I want to be able to use the following proxies.

`http://localhost:8181/a/ proxies request to the IP address of container 'a'`
`http://localhost:8181/b/ proxies request to the IP address of container 'b'`

To do this, I want to defer the management of each of the services nginx configuration to that service itself. Hopefully, this would allow each of the service to add/remove/modify entries to a `/etc/nginx/sites-available` volume that is shared with the containers and the host OS.

For example, I would think that I would need the following structure in NGINX

```
/etc/nginx
   - nginx.conf
   - sites-available
     - a
     - b
   - sites-enabled
     - a (sym link to sites-available/a)
     - b (sym link to sites-available/b)
```

The `nginx.conf` file looks like the following:

```
worker_processes  4;
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

Assuming that when I pull the IP addresses of the containers for `a` and `b` I get the following

`a -> 172.17.0.1`

`b -> 172.17.0.2`

and that I have container `a` exposing port `1234` and container `b` exposing port `5678`, what should the `a` and `b` files look like under `sites-available`?

I tried the following and similar variations, but can't seem to get it to use BOTH `/a` and `/b` proxies.

**excerpt from /etc/nginx/sites-available/a**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    location /a/ {
            proxy_pass http://172.17.0.1:1234/;
    }
}
```

**excerpt from /etc/nginx/sites-available/b**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    location /b/ {
            proxy_pass http://172.17.0.2:5678/;
    }
}
```

For example, using this configuration the following would be the results

`http://localhost:8181/a/ proxies to container 'a' just fine`

`http://localhost:8181/b/ gives a connection refused`

Comment: i think you should define `server_name` in each `config`, otherwise you should combine these two `config` into one within one `server` block.

Comment: I was able to get this working by fine, it turns out that it fails 'silently' if you restart nginx if command does not use `sudo`. @Freeznet if I was to use server_name, I would be bound to that hostname, and I dont want to use different hostnames for the different services. Additionally, I dont want them to be in a single config because then I cannot reload one service without having to reload another. I will add an answer of how I was able to get this working.